# how can i apply this css class

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am having trouble with applying this css to my HTML navbar I need to add this style for my HTML what should I do for it

```css
.menu2 li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: calibri;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu2">
  <li>
    <a href="#"></a>
    Help center
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"></a>
    Login
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <button class="btn">Get Start</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting text inside of the `<a>...</a>` tag?

Comment: Please mark my answer as helpful if it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML code seems buggy. You have empty `<a>` tags, with the text after the end of the element.

You probably meant:

```html
<li><a href="#">Help center</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS applies to the links (`<a href="#">...</a>` tags.) Your tags are empty.

Instead of this:

```
<li><a href="#"></a>Help center</li>
```

... do this:

```
<li><a href="#">Help center</a></li>
```

Without text inside of the link, what will the user click?

Answer (score 1):

Please put text inside your anchor tag.

```
<ul class="menu2">
 <li><a href="#">Help center</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" class="btn">Get Start</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Also you can get rid of button element and directly apply btn class to anchor element.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your text is outside the `a` tag.

```css
.menu2 li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: calibri;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu2">
  <li><a href="#">Help center</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Get Start</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using this :

```
 <ul class="menu2">
   <li><a href="#">Help center</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><button class="btn">Get Start</button></a></li>
</ul>
    .menu2 > li{
      color: #000;
      list-style: none;
      font-family: calibri;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      display: inline;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .menu2 > li > a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
```